# CSS problems across browsers, but IE working?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I am having problems placing a logo in my header.  The header is in a span of 257px.  It "appears" to place fine in Firefox/Chrome/Safari on both Mac and PC.  With IE 8/9 it "appears" the problem exits.  The twist here is that it actually works in IE and not the other browsers.  I really need at least 21px for the padding-top.

With the CSS below, IE is actually correctly rendering it but all the other browsers are adding close to 20px in the padding-top.

The CSS as it stands now, after many different iterations is.

```
.img {
    display: block;
    padding: 1px 0 21px 8px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
}
```

Any help tracking this down would be appreciated.

Comment: What if you use margin instead of padding?

Comment: @Marwelln it didn't make a difference, same results

Comment: You have not included enough information for your question to be answered properly. The answer below may work, but who knows? To *really* get it fixed, provide a link to your page. If that's not possible, then create a [JS Bin test case](http://jsbin.com/). You can copy the generated HTML source code of your file into a new file, copy all the relevant CSS stylesheets into `<style></style>`, and replace images with same sized versions from [http://dummyimage.com/](http://dummyimage.com/). Yes, that's annoying to do, but how much do you want your problem fixed?

Comment: Looks like my essay comment was a little late, oh well :)

Comment: @thirtydot Thanks for the info.  I was not aware of the site you posted or the one that netbrain posted.  Its been way too many hours at it today I will utilize those tomorrow and see if I can't track down if Yii is introducing the limitations and report back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about using absolute positioning withing a relative positioned span/div?

say for example:

```
<div style="position:relative;">
  <img src="..." style="position: absolute; top: 21px">
</div>
```

this would place the image 21px from the top of the parent div.

to illustrate it better. i made a jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/RD26R/

Comment: @netbrain, if my design was a bit more simple this would work.  I did not include that I am using Yii, thinking the framework should not introduce CSS problems.  The code for Yii looks like `<div class="span-7 img" id="header1"> 
                     <?php 
       $imghtml=CHtml::image(Yii::app()->request->baseUrl."image location","alt_name"); echo CHtml::link($imghtml, array('location'));
      ?>
                    </div>`  I don't understand how to incorporate your solution with this.  Let me pull the Yii code and retest.  Back in a few.

Comment: Could you give me the html output of this code? including the parent div?

Comment: Well the solution provided works if I take Yii out of the equation.  Not sure how the code I posted would affect something like this.  The parent is '<div class="span-26 last" id="header">' where span 26 = 960px.  I'll accept your solution and hit up the Yii board for common problems.  Normally I have to code specifically for IE not the other way around that is why I was so confused. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Well bottom line is that everything is HTML code at the end. So if you gave me the source code that the 'YII' component outputted then i might be able to help you further.

Comment: Here is the HTML...both together...`<div class="span-26 last" id="header">
        <div class="span-7 img" id="header1"> 
        <img src="img..." style="position: absolute; top:21px">

  <a href="img_location"><img src="img..." alt="name" /></a>                    
 </div>`

Comment: here is another example of how you can use css properties on your existing structure http://jsfiddle.net/RD26R/1/

Comment: @netbrain ok once again this solution works if i take Yii code out of the equation, I'll hunt done the Yii factor.  A side question here.  I always used blocks for my header logo but feel like there is more control with the solutions you provided.  Are your solutions really better than blocks?  Or should I only look at using them as a fall back solution?

Comment: if you are referring to the use of the combination for relative and absolute positioning. I would say they are the best bet for positioning elements. using margin and padding for positioning is not really my cup of tee. But it all comes down to the context. sometimes that may be the best solution and other times not at all. You decide!

Comment: Yeah I mean the use of relative and absolute positioning in the place of blocks (with padding and margins).  The final solution, came with somebody on the Yii board helping me get your code for absolute positioning into the Yii code I posted and now everything works as it should.  Thanks again for the help.